# Conditionally break columns into 2 lines?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, unicode

I have a file in the format of:

```
 ⌚..⌛    watch..hourglass
 ⌨️       keyboard
 ⏏️       eject button
```

Where some lines contain two entries. I want to break lines with 2 entries into 2 lines like so:

```
 ⌚       watch
 ⌛       hourglass
 ⌨️       keyboard
 ⏏️       eject button
```

Is there a fast way to do this?

---

**My script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wget -O output.txt http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/6.0/emoji-data.txt

sed -i '/^#/ d' output.txt                        # Remove comments                                                                                                          
sed -i 's/.*(//' output.txt                       # Remove columns not needed                                                                                               
sed -i 's|[(),]||g' output.txt                    # Remove brackets around emoji                                                                                         
sed -i 's/\(.*[^ ]\)[ ]*\(.*\)/\2 \1/' output.txt # Move first column to last                                                                         
sed -i '/^$/d' output.txt                         # Remove blank lines
```

---

Tried @RomanPerekhrest's answer on the following *(answer has been updated)*:

```
 ↔️..↙️    left-right arrow..down-left arrow
 ↩️..↪️    right arrow curving left..left arrow curving right
 ⌚..⌛    watch..hourglass done
 ⌨️       keyboard
```

*and it works on watch/hourglass but not the ones above(?)*

Comment: Seriously, when you need to do complex logic you'd be better off writing a Perl/Python script and call that script. After all, you're already calling an external program (`sed`). You don't even have to make the Python/Perl script a separate file; just embed the script in the bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*UPDATE*

Fixed an issue with some emoji being followed by the [variation-selector-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)), 
resulting in a bad formatting.

See @jimmij's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387483/182018), for an even more optimized sed script !

**sed**

```
 sed '/.\.\./ s/\(.\)\.\.\(\S*\)\s*\(.*\)\.\./\1\t\3\n \2\t/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another `sed` version, based on zeppelin answer, but simpler and aligned - taking care that unicode are not always single-characters. Tested with gnu `sed`.

```
sed 's/\.\.\([^ ]*\) *\(.*\)\.\./\t\2\n \1\t/'
```

Output:

```
 ↔️      left-right arrow
 ↙️      down-left arrow
 ↩️      right arrow curving left
 ↪️      left arrow curving right
 ⌚      watch
 ⌛      hourglass done
 ⌨️       keyboard
```

Comment: `sed` does match unicode characters correctly indeed (taking that you have a Unicode locale set), but some of the emoji are followed by [variation-selector-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_%28Unicode_block%29), which is a non-spacing mark (but not a part of the preceding character).

I've updated my answer to take it into account, after looking at yours :) 
Thx !

Comment: @zeppelin I didn't know about these "selectors", thanks. So technically speaking there are two unicode characters: original and the following selector, is that correct? If so, can original exist without selector block?

Comment: Yep, original character can exist w/o a variation selector. It is more like a display hint, see http://unicode.org/faq/vs.html for a more in-depth explanation of their role.

Comment: `\t\2\n \1\t` - Whitespace is not needed here. It do extra indent.

Comment: @MiniMax Yes it does, as a whitespace at the beginning of the line is present in the OP question.

Answer (score 3):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '$1~/\S\.\.\S/ && $2~/\S\.\.\S/{ 
         split($1,a,/\.\./); split($2,b,/\.\./); 
         printf("%s\t%s\n%s\t%s\n",a[1],b[1],a[2],b[2]); next 
     }1' file
```

- `-F'[[:space:]][[:space:]]+'` - field separator
- `$1~/\S\.\.\S/ && $2~/\S\.\.\S/` - if 2 fields contain `..` as *subitem* separator

The output:

```
↔️  left-right arrow
↙️  down-left arrow
↩️  right arrow curving left
↪️  left arrow curving right
⌚   watch
⌛   hourglass done
⌨️       keyboard
```

Comment: Sorry to slightly change my question but I'm trying to figure out why your code matches for the watch hourglass case but none of the other similar cases in my data file.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride, don't worry, see my update